# Get the confirmation url from a User resource in Devise 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

So Devise 3.1 now stores digest tokens in the database. I was using the stored token to send follow up e-mails to registered users, and if the user hadn't confirmed his e-mail yet, I would append a link with the token:

```
Please confirm your account etc.
www.example.com?confirmation_token=<%= user.confirmation_token %>
```

The problem is that now `user.confirmation_token` is encrypted, and I can't use the `@token` var because this action doesn't come from a Devise Controller.

Ultimately, I need a way to retrieve the correct confirmation URL from a User resource without passing through a Devise Controller.

Is there a way to do that?

**Edit:**

As there isn't a clear way to do that now, I opened an issue on Devise's Github for further ideas:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2903

Comment: @AnnArbor87: Please don't edit posts to add `random backticks`. Backticks should normally be used *only* for in-line program code. In this question, the only phrases that *should* have them are `@token` (which you did fix) and `user.confirmation_token` (which you did not). "Devise 3.1" and "Devise Controller", however, are *not* program code and should not have backticks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on when you are sending the email. If you are doing it at the same time that you are sending the usual confirmation email (so, within the same execution loop as when you create the User), you should be able to access the token by adding this to your User model:

```
def get_raw_confirmation_token
  return @raw_confirmation_token
end
```

If you are sending your follow-up email at a later point in time you will not be able to retrieve the existing confirmation token. It is stored in the database as a one-way hash for security purposes. What you can do however is generate a new confirmation token, and send that in your follow-up email. Add a new method to your User model like this:

```
def generate_new_confirmation_token
  unless @raw_confirmation_token
    generate_confirmation_token!
  end
  return @raw_confirmation_token       
end
```

This will invalidate your old token, but it will allow you to embed the new one into an email. Devise also provides the ability to resend the old confirmation email, simply call **resend_confirmation_instructions** on your user object and the email will be resent - if the confirmation token has expired, it will generate a new one for you.

Comment: Sounds reasonable from a security perspective, but it's terrible from the user perspective. I've had clients clicking the old activation link just to receive the message that it was no longer valid. So the user tries to resend the instructions and open again his e-mail in the next day. If the follow up is sent in the meantime, it'll invalidate the instructions again, to the point that the user simple give up and go away. I don't think this extra-security compensates the fact that I can lose users just because they can't confirm their accounts...

Comment: Yeah, it is one of those trade-offs that is very difficult to nail exactly. You could extend the confirmation period by setting the   config.confirm_within value to something longer (say 2 days) within the devise.rb initializer, which gives your users a bit more time to get around to confirming the account.